# Does the new Symbol Nuget package allow editing the Nuget locally?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-server

I'm investigating the new [.snupkg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/symbol-packages-snupkg) extension for Nuget packages and was wondering if it allows me to modify the Nuget code in Visual Studio on the fly or do I have to pack and push my new changed Nuget everytime I make a change I want to test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> wondering if it allows me to modify the Nuget code in Visual Studio on the fly or do I have to pack and push my new changed Nuget everytime I make a change I want to test?

I am afraid we could not modify the Nuget code in Visual Studio with the new `.snupkg` extension and still have to pack and push my new changed Nuget every time.

That because the new `.snupkg` extension is used to improve NuGet package **debugging** and symbols experience instead of automatically synchronizing code for nuget.

There are several issues with the NuGet package debugging and symbols experience before, the new `.snupkg` extension creates a streamlined package **debugging experience** for the entire NuGet ecosystem.

So, the new `.snupkg` extension is used to optimize debugging of nuget, we could not modify the Nuget code in Visual Studio directly and if we have any change in the nuget package, we still have to pack and push it.

You can check following document for some more details info.

[NuGet Package Debugging & Symbols Improvements](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/NuGet-Package-Debugging-&-Symbols-Improvements)

Hope this helps.